# Storing type in variable to declare properties

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, c#-8.0

To create a generic base class I want to have the type of my fields stored in variables. Something like this (THIS is just not working):

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            myType = typeof(string);
        }

        public Type myType { get; set; }

        public myType MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

I handle lots of models and ObservableCollections of models from a database with more than 70 tables that I get via Entity Framework Core and I don't want to copy/paste (DRY!) the business logic for every table just because of the type of changes.

Is there another approach to what I came up with?

Comment: `class MyClass<T> { ... public T MyProperty { get; set; } }`. AKA [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Comment: You will not be able to declare `public myType MyProperty`, and that is not just because that particular syntax is incorrect, there is no way to make the type runtime specified like that. You will either have to switch to a generic class, like @Cid showed, or use `object` or `dynamic` for the actual property type, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've seen, what you are trying to do is simply not possible. A variable of type `Type` cannot be used to declare another variable. (The same applies for fields, properties, etc). What you are looking for is called [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/), specifically [generic classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes). Here is what your code would look like with a generic class:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
   public T MyProperty { get; set; } 
   public Type TypeOfT => typeof(T); // for demo
}
```

In the above example, `T` (called the generic type parameter) is a sort of placeholder. It can be replaced with any* class/struct/interface. This is done when you create a new instance of the type:

```
var objInt = new MyClass<int>();
Console.WriteLine(objInt.TypeOfT.Name); // System.Int32
objInt.MyProperty = 5;

var objString = new MyClass<string>();
Console.WriteLine(objString.TypeOfT.Name); // System.String
objString.MyProperty = "Hello!";
```

They may even be used with *other* generic types:

```
var obj = new MyClass<MyClass<string>>();
obj.MyProperty = new MyClass<string>();
obj.MyProperty.MyProperty = "World";
Console.WriteLine(obj.TypeOfT.Name); // MyClass`1
Console.WriteLine(obj.MyProperty.TypeOfT.Name); // System.String
```

The type parameter remains consistent thoroughout the entire class. It can appear in properties, fields, return types and method parameters. A class can have multiple type parameters as well. Additionally, [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) may specify generic arguments with or without their containing class being generic themselves.

I suggest following up with reading the docs pointed to by the above links. Generics is quite a big topic--one that cannot be done justice here.

* There are *some* types that cannot be used as generic arguments, for example `ref structs`